# Build expo React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, npm-install, yarnpkg

`Running "yarn install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory

yarn install v1.22.19

[1/4] Resolving packages...

[stderr]
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "@expo/webpack-config@^49.0.0". Ignoring it.

[stderr]
error Couldn't find any versions for "@expo/webpack-config" that matches "^49.0.0"

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

yarn exited with non-zero code: 1`

Problem on react native expo build.

Answer (score 1):

From [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/webpack-config):

The latest version for this package is 18.1.1. You are using 49.0.0.
Update the version and it should work.